# How to send email in laravel after May 30, 2022

Tags: laravel, smtp, gmail

- My laravel website have feature send email, but after 30 may 2022 it can't working. How can i fix it ? My laravel version is 5.8.
- My .env
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi9U5.png)
- Failed
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qerix.png)

Please help me!
Thank you

Comment: did you try application password instead of your regular gmail password there?

Comment: @LIGHT can you explain it more ?, thank you

Comment: You need to use application password, not your gmail password. here's how you create it:

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en